# Reducing size of e-book on .MOBI file. Or any alternative to .MOBI file for KDP

Tags: kindle, mobi, kdp

I´m working on a e-book for kids with some images on it. I want to load to Amazon Kindle KDP.

1. I have a book that it is only 26 pages and that it would have about 25 images.
2. I tried to load the file in the Amazon KDP webside in word and pdf format and the whole formating is mess-up so the only way I found the format is correct is with using "Kindle Kids Book creator" and converting it to .MOBI
3. Kindle Kids Book is created by uploading a PDF
4. Initially my word document was 2.5MB --> 1,8MB the PDF --> Converted to 8.3MB the .MOBI File --> and 4.48MB the final or "fee" file
5. I tried to reduce my word document to reduced the size of the final file but the .MOBI and final final are still the same size
6. After reducing to 1.8MB --> 1,2MB the PDF --> Converted to 8.3MB the .MOBI File --> and 4.48MB the final or "fee" file

I´m sure I´m doing something wrong but I don´t know where:

1. It is not normal that other poeple told me that with the same number of images and 300 more pages his final file is 1.8MG and my file is 4.48MB
2. Is there any way to reduce the .MOBI file size??

Any help or clue it would be highly appreciate. Please considered that I´m totally new at this, so don´t fell bad talking to me like I´m a little baby

Thank you very much to all of you

Comment: Why is a pdf involved here. Surely you should go direct from Word to mobi (or via epub). PDF is not reflowable text so will hard code a lot of things in - including the size

Answer (score 0):

> It is not normal that other poeple told me that with the same number of images and 300 more pages his final file is 1.8MG and my file is 4.48MB

That measurement is not reliable and can very wildy based on the image quality and compression potential. Besides, 1.8 mb to 4.5 mb is not a big deal to worry about.

> Is there any way to reduce the .MOBI file size??

How are you generating the mobi? Kindle Previewer or Kindlegen actually pack multiple formats into the result. For example Calibre's converter only outputs one format, thus reducing the file size. But as I said, the file size is not really anything to worry about.